# Spring Web Application doesn't supports both GET and POST

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, pagination

I am supporting a web application developed in Spring MVC and Sitemesh. I have to add pagination capability in one of the pages in the application. I am getting the same page loaded first time with N number of records as I mentioned as MaximumResults in Hibernate. But when I click the Next button, it is saying that the POST method is not supported and supported method is GET. I then changed the respective method type in Controller and Form to GET. But then it is saying that GET is not supported and supported method is POST.

I removed the Sitemesh configuration itself and tried as I read Sitemesh sometimes creates the issue though it didn't works. I tried to replace the `<mvc:resources>` configuration as well with SimpleHttpRequestHandler though there were no joy.

Please see the respective JSP, Controller, Spring Configuration and web.xml attached .

Triggering page:

```
<form:form id="form-${eta.paymentPeriod.period}"  method="post" modelAttribute="etaForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/performance/searchPeriodSpecificETADetails.htm">
    <tr>
        <input name="courierId" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaDetails.courierId}"/>"/>
        <input name="year" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${eta.paymentPeriod.year}"/>"/>
        <input name="period" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${eta.paymentPeriod.period}"/>"/>
        <input name="timeslot" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${eta.timeSlot}"/>"/>
        <input name="daysPassed" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${eta.daysPassed}"/>"/>
        <input name="percentage" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${eta.percentage}"/>"/>
                            
        <td style="padding-left:10px; color:blue;">
            <button type="submit" class="link"><span><c:out value="P${eta.paymentPeriod.period}"/></span></button>
            <%-- <a href="#" id="<c:out value="${eta.paymentPeriod.period}"/>" class="empty"> ${eta.paymentPeriod.period} </a> --%>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left:40px"> <c:out value="${eta.timeSlot}"/> </td>
        <td style="padding-left:20px"> <c:out value="${eta.percentage}"/> </td>
        <td style="padding-left:30px"> <c:out value="${eta.daysPassed}"/> </td>
        <td style="padding-left:30px"> <c:out value="${eta.daysFailed}"/> </td>                                 
    </tr>
</form:form>
```

*Paginated JSP:

```
                            <c:forEach var="eta" items="${etaDaySpecificDetails}">
                                <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="etaForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/performance/searchPeriodSpecificETAFailureDetails.htm">
                                    <tr>
                                        <c:set var="failed" value="${eta.set - eta.passed}"/>
                                        <c:if test="${eta.passed == eta.set}">
                                            <fmt:formatNumber value="100" var="success" maxFractionDigits="1"/>
                                        </c:if>
                                        <c:if test="${eta.passed != eta.set}">
                                            <fmt:formatNumber value="${(eta.passed / eta.set)*100}" var="success" maxFractionDigits="1"/>
                                        </c:if>
                                        <fmt:formatDate value="${eta.date}" var="etaDate" pattern="E d MMM" />
                                        
                                        <input name="year" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaSummery.year}"/>"/>
                                        <input name="period" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaSummery.period}"/>"/>
                                        <input name="timeslot" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaSummery.timeslot}"/>"/>
                                        <input name="courierId" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaSummery.courierId}"/>"/>
                                        <input name="dateId" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${eta.dateId}"/>"/>
                                        <input name="date" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${eta.date}"/>"/>
                                        <input name="daysPassed" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaSummery.daysPassed}"/>"/>
                                        <input name="percentage" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaSummery.percentage}"/>"/>
                                        
                                        <td style="padding-left: 10px; color: blue;"><c:out value="${etaDate}" /></td>
                                        <td style="padding-left: 10px"><c:out value="${eta.set}" /></td>
                                        <td style="padding-left: 20px"><c:out value="${eta.modified}" /></td>
                                        <td style="padding-left: 30px"><c:out value="${eta.cancelled}" /></td>
                                        <td style="padding-left: 30px"><c:out value="${eta.passed}" /></td>
                                        <c:if test="${failed > 0}">
                                            <td style="padding-left:30px;"> 
                                                <button type="submit" id="failure_link_${eta.dateId}" class="link" style="color:red;text-decoration: underline;"><span><c:out value="${failed}"/></span></button>
                                            </td>
                                        </c:if>
                                        <c:if test="${failed == 0}">
                                            <td style="padding-left: 30px"><c:out value="${failed}" /></td>
                                        </c:if>
                                        <td style="padding-left: 15px"><c:out value="${success}" /> %</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </form:form>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </table>
                    
                        <form:form id="form-next"  method="POST" modelAttribute="etaForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/performance/searchPeriodSpecificETADetailsNextRecord.htm">
                                <input name="year" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaSummery.year}"/>"/>
                                <input name="period" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaSummery.period}"/>"/>
                                <input name="timeslot" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaSummery.timeslot}"/>"/>
                                <input name="courierId" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaSummery.courierId}"/>"/>
                                <input name="paginationMetaInfo" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${etaSummery.paginationMetaInfo}"/>"/>
                            
                                <td style="padding-left:10px; color:blue;">
                                <button type="submit" class="link"><span>Next</span></button>
<%--                                    <a href="#" id="<c:out value="${eta.paymentPeriod.period}"/>" class="empty"> ${eta.paymentPeriod.period} </a> --%>
                        </form:form>
```

**Controller **

```
    @Controller
@SessionAttributes("courierDetails")
@RequestMapping("performance")
public class CourierPerformanceController {

private CourierPerformanceManager courierPerformanceManager;

@Autowired
private MessageSource messages;
 
private MyPerformanceManager myPerformanceManager; 

private BeanPropertyCopier beanPropertyCopier;

@Value("${info.myperformance.depot.secondTarget}")
private Double depoSecondTarget;

@Value("${info.myperformance.delivery.secondTarget}")
private Double deliverySecondTarget;

@Value("${info.myperformance.collection.secondTarget}")
private Double collectionSecondTarget;

private static final String DOZ_ETA_VO_TO = "etaVOToEtaTo";
private static final String ATTR_ETA_DAY_SPECIFIC_DETAILS = "etaDaySpecificDetails";
private static final String ATTR_ETA_DAY_SPECIFIC_FAILURE_DETAILS = "etaDaySpecificFailureDetails";
private static final String ATTR_ETA_SUMMERY = "etaSummery";
private static final String ATTR_ETA_DETAILS = "etaDetails";
private static final String DATA_TYPE_JSON = "application/json";

@Autowired
public CourierPerformanceController(MyPerformanceManager myPerformanceManager,CourierPerformanceManager courierPerformanceManager, 
        BeanPropertyCopier beanPropertyCopier) {
    
    this.myPerformanceManager = myPerformanceManager;
    this.courierPerformanceManager = courierPerformanceManager;
    this.beanPropertyCopier = beanPropertyCopier;
    
}

private DataTables buildDataTables(CourierDetails courierDetails) throws CouriersException {
    
      MyPerformanceResults results = myPerformanceManager.getPerformanceDetails(courierDetails.getCrId());
     
      return CourierPerformanceGraphUtil.createAndInitializeDataTableWithCourierPerformanceDetails(results, messages);
      
}

   @RequestMapping(
            value = {   
                        WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_GET_SEARCH_ENQUIRY_PEFORMANCE_DETAILS,
                        WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_GET_SEARCH_COLLECTION_PEFORMANCE_DETAILS,
                        WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_GET_SEARCH_RECEIPT_PEFORMANCE_DETAILS,
                        WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_GET_SEARCH_DELIVERY_PEFORMANCE_DETAILS}, 
                    


                        method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = DATA_TYPE_JSON)

public @ResponseBody DataTables searchCourierEnquiryPerformanceDetails(@ModelAttribute CourierDetails courierDetails, HttpServletRequest session)
        throws CouriersException {

    DataTables dataTables = buildDataTables(courierDetails );
    
    return dataTables;
}

@RequestMapping(
        value = WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_GET_ETA_DETAILS_FOR_PRIMARY_TAB, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView searchCourierETAPerformanceDetailsForPrimaryTab(@ModelAttribute CourierDetails courierDetails,Model model, HttpServletRequest session)
        throws CouriersException {

    ETASearchCriteria searchCriteria = new ETASearchCriteria();
    searchCriteria.setCourierId(courierDetails.getCrId());
    resetPaginationMetaInfo();
    final ETADetails etaDetails = courierPerformanceManager.searchETAForAllAvailablePeriods(searchCriteria);
    return new ModelAndView(SPRING_VIEW_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_COURIER_ETA_PERFORMANCE_DETAILS, ATTR_ETA_DETAILS , etaDetails);
}

@RequestMapping(
        value = WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_GET_DELIVERY_PEFORMANCE_DETAILS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView redirectToCourierDeliveryDetails(@ModelAttribute CourierDetails courierDetails, HttpServletRequest session)
        throws CouriersException {
    return new ModelAndView(SPRING_VIEW_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_COURIER_ETA_DELIVERY_DETAILS);
}

@RequestMapping(
        value = WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_GET_RECEIPT_PEFORMANCE_DETAILS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView redirectToCourierReceiptDetails(@ModelAttribute CourierDetails courierDetails, HttpServletRequest session)
        throws CouriersException {
    return new ModelAndView(SPRING_VIEW_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_MYPERFORMANCE);
}

@RequestMapping(
        value = WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_GET_COLLECTION_PEFORMANCE_DETAILS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView redirectToCourierCollectionDetails(@ModelAttribute CourierDetails courierDetails, HttpServletRequest session)
        throws CouriersException {
    return new ModelAndView(SPRING_VIEW_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_COURIER_COLLECTION_DETAILS);
}

@RequestMapping(
        value = WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_GET_ENQUIRY_PEFORMANCE_DETAILS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView redirectToCourierEnquiryDetails(@ModelAttribute CourierDetails courierDetails, HttpServletRequest session)
        throws CouriersException {
    return new ModelAndView(SPRING_VIEW_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_COURIER_ENQUIRY_DETAILS);
}

@RequestMapping(
        value = WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_POST_SERACH_PERIOD_SPECIFIC_ETA_DETAILS, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchPeriodSpecificETADetails(@ModelAttribute CourierDetails courierDetails,@ModelAttribute("etaForm")
        ETAValueObject etaValueObject , Model model,
        HttpServletRequest session) throws CouriersException {
    List<DaySpecificETAInformation> etaDetails = searchETADetailsForSpecificPeriod(etaValueObject);
    model.addAttribute(ATTR_ETA_DAY_SPECIFIC_DETAILS, etaDetails);
    model.addAttribute(ATTR_ETA_SUMMERY, etaValueObject);
    return SPRING_VIEW_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_COURIER_ETA_DAY_SPECIFIC_PERF_DETAILS;
}    

@RequestMapping(
        value = WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_POST_SERACH_PERIOD_SPECIFIC_ETA_DETAILS_NEXT_RECORD, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchPeriodSpecificETADetailsNextRecord(@ModelAttribute CourierDetails courierDetails,@ModelAttribute("etaForm")
        ETAValueObject etaValueObject , Model model,
        HttpServletRequest session) throws CouriersException {
    List<DaySpecificETAInformation> etaDetails = searchETADetailsForSpecificPeriod(etaValueObject);
    model.addAttribute(ATTR_ETA_DAY_SPECIFIC_DETAILS, etaDetails);
    model.addAttribute(ATTR_ETA_SUMMERY, etaValueObject);
    return SPRING_VIEW_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_COURIER_ETA_DAY_SPECIFIC_PERF_DETAILS;
}   
@RequestMapping(
        value = WEB_REQUEST_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_POST_SERACH_PERIOD_SPECIFIC_ETA_FAIL_DETAILS, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchDaySpecificETAFailureInformation(@ModelAttribute CourierDetails courierDetails,@ModelAttribute
        ETAValueObject etaValueObject , Model model,
        HttpServletRequest session) throws CouriersException {
    List<DaySpecificETAFailureInformation> etaDetails = searchDaySpecificETAFailureInformation(etaValueObject);
    model.addAttribute(ATTR_ETA_DAY_SPECIFIC_FAILURE_DETAILS, etaDetails);
    model.addAttribute(ATTR_ETA_SUMMERY, etaValueObject);
    return SPRING_VIEW_URL.COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_COURIER_ETA_DAY_SPECIFIC_FAIL_DETAILS;
}    

private List<DaySpecificETAInformation> searchETADetailsForSpecificPeriod(ETAValueObject etaValueObject) {
    
    ETASearchCriteria searchCriteria = copyDetailsFromSourceToDestination(etaValueObject, ETASearchCriteria.class, DOZ_ETA_VO_TO);
    availSearchResultsCountForETADetailsForSpecificPeriod(searchCriteria,etaValueObject);
    List<DaySpecificETAInformation> etaDetails = courierPerformanceManager.searchETADetailsForSpecificPeriod(searchCriteria);
    
    return etaDetails;
}

private void availSearchResultsCountForETADetailsForSpecificPeriod(ETASearchCriteria searchCriteria,ETAValueObject etaValueObject) {
    PaginationMetaInfo paginationMetaInfoFromView = etaValueObject.getPaginationMetaInfo();
    
    if(paginationMetaInfoFromView == null) {
        paginationMetaInfoFromView = PaginationMetaInfo.getPaginationMetaInfo();
        Integer maximumResults = courierPerformanceManager.findSearchResultsCountForETAFailureDetailsForSpecificDateAndPeriod(searchCriteria);
        paginationMetaInfoFromView.setMaximumResults(maximumResults);
        etaValueObject.setPaginationMetaInfo(paginationMetaInfoFromView);
    }
    
    PaginationMetaInfo.addPaginationMetaInfo(paginationMetaInfoFromView);
    
    paginationMetaInfoFromView.updateNextRowIndex();
    
}

private void resetPaginationMetaInfo() {
    PaginationMetaInfo.addPaginationMetaInfo(new PaginationMetaInfo());
    PaginationMetaInfo.getPaginationMetaInfo().setNextRowIndex(0);
}

private List<DaySpecificETAFailureInformation> searchDaySpecificETAFailureInformation(ETAValueObject etaValueObject) {
     
    ETASearchCriteria searchCriteria = copyDetailsFromSourceToDestination(etaValueObject, ETASearchCriteria.class, DOZ_ETA_VO_TO);
    List<DaySpecificETAFailureInformation> etaDetails = courierPerformanceManager.searchETAFailureDetailsForSpecificDateAndPeriod(searchCriteria);
    
    return etaDetails;
     
}

private <T> T copyDetailsFromSourceToDestination(Object src, Class<T> clazz, String mappingName) {
    return beanPropertyCopier.copyDetailsFromSourceToDestination(src, clazz, mappingName);
}

}
```

I am hitting the searchPeriodSpecificETADetails from the first page and searchPeriodSpecificETADetailsNextRecord for the paginated results.

```
    static String COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_POST_SERACH_PERIOD_SPECIFIC_ETA_DETAILS = "/searchPeriodSpecificETADetails";
static String COUR_PERF_CONTROLLER_HTTP_POST_SERACH_PERIOD_SPECIFIC_ETA_DETAILS_NEXT_RECORD = "/searchPeriodSpecificETADetailsNextRecord.htm";
```

**Spring Configuration**

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/fonts/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />

<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

**Web.xml**

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>sitemeshGeneralFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>uk.co.hermes.filters.SitemeshGeneralFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemeshGeneralFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Sitemesh Filter**

```
public class SitemeshGeneralFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {
private final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SitemeshGeneralFilter.class);

public SitemeshGeneralFilter() {
    super();
}

/**
 * See http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh3/Configuring+SiteMesh+3
 */
@Override
protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {
    // apply this decorator (template) to the path defined...
    builder.addDecoratorPath("/*", "/WEB-INF/jsp/sitemeshDecorators/generalDecorator.jsp")
    // ... when the response type matches one of these
    .setMimeTypes("text/html", "application/xhtml+xml", "application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml");``
}}
```

It would be really great if someone can help me.

Comment: please share URL your form trying to access As POST

Comment: Hope this is what you asked for.....<form:form id="form-next"  method="POST" modelAttribute="etaForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/performance/searchPeriodSpecificETADetailsNextRecord.htm">

Comment: I hit searchPeriodSpecificETADetails for details which needs to be rendered in the second page in paginated passion. From the second page, it hits searchPeriodSpecificETADetailsNextRecord to fetch subsequent records. searchPeriodSpecificETADetails AND searchPeriodSpecificETADetailsNextRecord are the respective controller methods in order.

Comment: The point is this error will happened if you are sending post request to URL not have method=POST in requestmapping.

Comment: But I do have both methods mapped to RequestMethod.POST though it is throwing the same error always [searchPeriodSpecificETADetailsNextRecord & searchPeriodSpecificETADetails]. It also tells that supported method is GET when I map the methods to POST and supported method is POST if the same method is mapped to GET.